# Show empty UITableView row from core data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to mimic the iPhone calendar list view and show my appointments in a list. Regardless if I have appointments for "Today" I would like to have a section with today's date. With my below fetchController how would I check and then if no appointments exist for today, add an empty section and not mess up the sorting?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

//    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
//        return fetchedResultsController;
//    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Appointments" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Sort using the date / then time property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorTime = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start_time" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorDate, sortDescriptorTime, nil];


    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Use the sectionIdentifier property to group into sections.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like this can be done with `NSFetchedResultsController`, there is a 3rd party class that manipulates this data though so you can add empty rows.

https://github.com/timothyarmes/TAFetchedResultsController

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];` this will return 0 if there is no results. Since you're using a NSFetchedResultController, you'll have to do some playing around in your tableView methods in order to display something that's not in the results controller. So you could do e countForFetchRequest first, then if it's 0 go ahead and display what you need in the table.

Comment: Well what I need is to display a header with no rows for the current date, if their are no rows for the current date.